# Relationship between moment of inertia of a solid with respect to a point and moments of inertia with respect to the axes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics

My calculus book defines the moments of inertia of a solid with respect to the coordinate axes, as:

[image]

and the moment of inertia with respect to the origin as
[image]

The $I_0$ definition looks inconsistent with the previous ones
Trying to prove it, I get:
$I_0=I_x+I_y+I_z = \int_\Omega 2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \mu(x,y,z)dxdydz$
Besides I can't figure out what  the physical interpretation of moment of inertia of a solid with respect to a point is.
How do I make sense of it?

Comment: Which book is this? Other sources instead have (in your book's terms) $I_0 = \frac{1}{2}(I_x+I_y+I_z)$ and obtain the same result you would. See for instance [section 2.19](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Book%3A_Classical_Mechanics_(Tatum)/02%3A_Moments_of_Inertia/2.19%3A_Moment_of_Inertia_with_Respect_to_a_Point) of Tatum's classical mechanics text. The following statement there is also relevant: "I cannot relate it in an obvious way to a simple dynamical concept in the same way that I related moment of inertia with respect to an axis to rotational inertia...".

Comment: So, while the computed quantity may be quite useful (it is rotation-invariant!) the direct physical interpretation may be much more tenuous.

Comment: @Semiclassical: it's an calculus italian book: Mathematical analysis II-Canuto, Tabacco.  , Indeed, rotation of a solid about a point , makes no sense to me, and also notice the mass density does not depend on z anymore

Comment: I was able to track down the page of interest on Google Books ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=b03asMD4ezsC&pg=PA330), bottom of the page.) So that indeed is the tack they take. As best I can tell, though, this is not consistent with either their own definitions or with wider practice. For a historical source, see Lester's 1909 (!) text on classical mechanics ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=7tsR0uBz1NkC&pg=PA46)).

Comment: Thanks, now I am  surer this definition is wrong

Comment: It also seems to be wrong in the original Italian version ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=x2JmYi3nxa4C&pg=PA342)).

Comment: yeah, I am actually using that one

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in how Moment of Inertia is defines for a point and an axis. Nonetheless, it's the integral of the product of distance of infinitesimally small points on/inside a solid and the mass of those points. To be precise,

Moment of Inertia= $\int_{\Omega}$(distance of the section from the point/line)*(mass of the infinitesimally small section)

Now the mass density is constant for any solid. But the distance :

From origin = $x^2+y^2+z^2$

From X-Axis = $y^2+z^2$

From Y-Axis = $x^2+z^2$

From Z-Axis = $x^2+y^2$

You can clearly see how $I_0 = 1/2(I_x+I_y+I_z)$ unlike the book.